# if condition not working in jquery for responseTest from server

Tags: jquery

This is my code working only when I make comment the SECOND if portion.

```
        function checkUsername() {                
            var xRequest;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                xRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if ((xRequest.readyState == 4) && (xRequest.status == 200)) {                                                 
                    var d=xRequest.responseText;
                    var bdy = $(d).filter('#a').text();
                    alert(bdy);
                   // if(bdy == 'false'){
                       // document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor="red";

                    //}esle{
                       // document.getElementById("username").style.borderColor="green";                            
                   // }                        
                }
            }
            uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
            xRequest.open("get", "checkUsername.jsp?uname="+uname, true);
            xRequest.send();               
        }
```

but i want to check true and false returning from the server.

Comment: what is the `xRequest.responseText` value?

Comment: You've spelt 'else' wrong.  You have spelt it 'esle' in the commented out section.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because of a typo in your function. You wrote `esle` instead of `else`. Everything  else seems o.k.